# Calculation in php goes wrong

Tags: php

Something is wrong with my code, these are the errors displayed in the browser

> Notice: Undefined offset: 86186 in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Villa\berekening.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 123123 in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Villa\berekening.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 123123 in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Villa\berekening.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 369369 in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Villa\berekening.php on line 34

I have no clue what I did wrong
[image: The errors]

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: If you're going to include code you need to copy the text into the question rather than putting it in an image. Images can't be searched and it makes it harder for people to help with your problem. Please edit your question and put the relevant code from the screenshot into your question.

Comment: My crystal ball isn't clear enough today to read the code in your berekening.php file to see what's wrong

Comment: Please copy your code into your question with the <code> tag instead of using an image

Comment: edit your question to include the code instead of the linked image and I will post the answer I already prepared for you.

Comment: PHP rule #1 - if you cannot guarantee a variable to exists, initialize it and use `isset()` to avoid undefined xxx notices / warnings.

Answer (score 4):

After reading you code I see that you're trying to do this :

Display `$brutot`, `$netto`, `$spaargId`.

But why are you trying to put them into a `$_POST` ?

Just do the following instead of your lines 28-30 :

```
echo $brutoTot;
echo $netto;
echo $spaargeld;
```

But you should also as Alex Andrei suggested check if your GET value are existing before using them to avoid any kind of undefined index so at the top of your PHP you should create your vars like below:

```
if(isset($_GET['netto'])){
    $netto = $_GET['netto'];
}
if(isset($_GET['bruto'])){
    $bruto = $_GET['bruto'];
}
if(isset($_GET['spaargeld'])){
    $spaargeld = $_GET['spaargeld'];
}
if(isset($_GET['ExtraInkomsten'])){
    $ExtraInkomsten = $_GET['ExtraInkomsten'];
}
```

Comment: this does not solve the OP's `undefined offset` notices, since your answer doesn't check if `GET` is actually populated

Comment: Well OP's undefined offset were here because he was trying to echo unexisting offset of $_POST(which hadn't any reason to be used in this context) so ...

Comment: actually `undefined offset` will trigger for `GET` also, when the `form` is not posted

Comment: edited to include securization on $_GET

Answer (score 0):

don't need to use **$_POST** just echo out the result

```
echo $brutoTot;
echo $netto;
echo $spaargeId;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have no $_POST values with those indexes. You can var_dump your $_POST to verify this and see what you can address.

Comment: this is not an answer, use the comment section